can't connect to wpa3 only network (SAE-H2E)
I'm using wpa_supplicant v2.10 and am trying to connect to wpa3 network with wpa_cli using following recommended configuration:
add_network
set_network 0 ssid "mySsid"
set_network 0 key_mgmt SAE
set_network 0 sae_password "myPassword"
set_network 0 ieee80211w 2
enable 0

with debug enabled I get:

wlan0: 0: d2:c2:82:f2:32:bf ssid='mySsid' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x411 level=-39 freq=2437
wlan0:    selected based on RSN IE SAE-PK: Not a valid password
(length)

AFAIK the length of sae_password is restricted the same way as psk passwork (ie. length 8-63 charecters)
so I don't anderstand what am I doing wrong.

other devices are able to connect to this network.
sae was enabled when compiling
my HW supports PMF:


iw phy phy0 info | grep 00-0f-ac:6

CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)


any help would be very much appreciated

Hello, we could use more informationfor example, what is the device, the OS, also can you check if your driver support WPA3 and update it ?

thanks alot! we are using NL80211 driver (linux). guess we need to update the driver.

Thank you for the information, keep us updated.
